# Regular Express: Selecting text that doesn't begin with a certain character

Tags: regex

I am attempting to use regexp to parse a basic CSS selector, such as the following: "tag.class#id tag"

I have been able to match the class using `/\.\w+/`, the ID using `/#\w+/`, and I have been able to match the final tag (plus the space preceding it) using `/[^\.#\w+]\w+/`, but so far I have been unable to find a way to match both tags.

My attempts to match the words that don't begin with '#' and '.', such as using `/[^#.]\w+/` (which matches everything but '.' and '#'), or using lookbehind like `/(?<!#)\w+/` (which matches nothing), have failed.

Is there a way to match a group of word characters as long as it DOESN'T begin with a certain character, like '.' or '#'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use:

```
/\w+/g
```

Then it will return you all the words that will contain any of these characters:

```
]a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

This doesn't include `.` or `#`

However if you want to capture any non-space group of characters that is not  `.` and `#` then use:

```
/[^.#\s]+/g
```

This will match anything but  `.` and `#` and a white-space.

If you have lookbehind supported then you can use:

```
/(?<![.#])\b([^.#\s]+)\b/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJ8iV7/1)

Comment: Unfortunately that is matching 'tag', 'class', 'id', and 'tag', while I'm trying to only match both instances of 'tag'.

Comment: Given the input is `"tag.class#id tag"` what is your expected output?

Comment: Also tell in what language are you doing this.

Comment: @anubhava , does it matter what language he's doing this (likely CSS?), I thought RegEx was the same across all languages. Please correct if wrong. Thx!

Comment: @anubhava I am working in Ruby. The output expected would be a match set of `['tag', 'tag']`. 'tag' itself is generic, but in a real CSS use case this would be something like `"div.class_name p"`, where it would match `['div', 'p']`.

Comment: @Mark: does updated regex and demo link work for you? I believe Ruby may not support look behind though.

Comment: @anubhava That works perfectly! Also, Ruby does support lookbehind.

Comment: Glad it worked and thanks for the tip of look behind in ruby.